# Как сделать несколько параметров для OnClick?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как добавить несколько атрибутов в `OnClick`. 
Есть код:

```
onclick="yaCounter.reachGoal ('tel'); return true;"
```

Как мне к `OnClick` добавить еще код? `fbq('track', 'Lead');`

Спасибо.

Comment: `onclick="yaCounter.reachGoal ('tel'); fbq('track', 'Lead'); return true;"  `

Comment: я  бы обработку событий вынес все же в js.  потому что  искать где что и на что подписано будет трудно потом  при росте количества кода

Answer (score 2):

Можно вот так

```
onclick="yaCounter.reachGoal('tel'); fbq('track', 'Lead'); return true;"
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую. А в конец после "true" нельзя вставить?

Comment: @inTeamo нет, поскольку return возвращает значение для отправки формы. То, что будет после return, обрабатываться не будет.

Comment: Нельзя, так как return true в обработчике заканчивает его выполнение.

Comment: Не хочет пиксель работать после нажатия на кнопку...

Comment: Возможно проблема именно в коде функции fbq?

Comment: @DenisPetrov вряд ли, скорее всего пробел перед ('tel') :)